# Invoke default browser from C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How to invoke the default browser with an URL from C#?

Answer (score 18):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

More details here -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326951.aspx

Answer (score 6):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://mysite.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

I used System.Diagnostics.Process.Start in the past, but if Firefox or another browser is set as the default this method always throws a terrible exception to users. At last, I come across System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp

`Help.ShowHelp(null, "http://www.google.com");`

Please notice that Help is a class only available for WinForms, while Process can be used for other cases (WebForms, WPF and so on).