# Environment variables interfering with jar

Tags: classpath, environment-variables, executable-jar

I have a jar file, which *works* in many machines. However we just asked for a new unix user to install it, and it is not behaving the same... wonder if it could be anything related to some env. var.

the basic idea is:

```
WorkingUser@box$ java -jar install.jar -h
[output help instructions]
```

but then

```
NewUser@box$ java -jar install.jar -h
The java class is not found:  pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.Loader
```

Before anyone asks, there is not classpath needed and yes, the cksum for the jar is ok. in fact:

```
$ jar tf install.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
pkg1/
pkg1/pkg2/
pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/
pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/script/
pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/Loader.class
pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/LoaderHelper.class
package.jar
```

And you can figure that the `MANIFEST.MF` is fine, since it works in other users.

I have tried executing with `-cp install.jar` with no success. Also the `$CLASSPATH` for working and not working users contains only "`.`".

any clues?

thanks,

f.

Comment: I have some more data and I'm running this question on serverfault. please close this. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke default browser from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232625/invoke-default-browser-from-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm copping the answer from [davey](https://serverfault.com/users/5894/davey) in serverfault to have this closed. follows.

Try copying the file to /tmp or /var/tmp and running the install from there. Does it get further/succeed?

**[EDIT]**

This was pretty close to the actual problem. I ended up doing a similar test which worked and  which with some testing lead me to find that the *mount point* permissions were wrong, i.e. the folder where the user's fs is mounted belongs to *root* and had access `774` (no exec to *others*).

I find always fascinating how wrong permissions in a low level cause the most adverse effects in the upper layers. I had (and I'm still not quite sure of it) that the permissions of the mount point had affect the mounted fs...

Anyways, we gave it the exec permission and *voilá*, java finds it's classes. There are more problems with this whole installation, but these might go to other questions :)

Thanks all.